# Sql select inner joine and union 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join, union

I have been trying to union three and join one table, i was successfully in selecting using only inner join and also combining the inner join and union bu my problem is to get reply id i have tried many thing to display reply id but keep getting error while other work fine

**Bellow sql give me this**

```
     //$dsnnot->prepare("SELECT * FROM replys r INNER JOIN blog_post b ON r.rid = b.BID WHERE b.UserName = :ownerna AND r.read = 1");        
        
        $dsnnot->prepare('SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT "post" AS type, BID AS eid, blog_title AS title, Time AS stime, blog_body AS description, UserName AS owner FROM blog_post b 
INNER JOIN replys r ON r.rid = b.BID WHERE b.action = "active" AND r.read = 1
            UNION 
            SELECT "jaile" AS , jid AS eid, orgname AS title, jaildate AS stime, OrgDescription AS description, jailorgnowner AS owner FROM jailorgname
            UNION
            SELECT "articl" AS type, TID AS eid, Atitle AS title, Atime AS stime, Abody AS description, Auser AS owner FROM articlespost
            
        ) foo  WHERE owner = :ownerna');
```

**I was able to output by this**

> type > Show where it came from
>
> eid > Show main post id's
>
> title > Show post title
>
> owner  > Show post author
>
> stime > Show time
>
> description > Show post content

Now my problem is to show `replys` > RID, i want to also out put it in my php

Comment: Please guys i need to fix this don't vote my question down

Comment: Post your question with much more additional information.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan that was the only explanation i have for this question if you want me to attach all my code before you can help me i will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the same number of columns and the columns from each SELECT must be of the same data type in the same order. So if you want the reply id you have to add a null to each select that you're not selecting from.

```
$dsnnot->prepare('
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    "post" AS type,
    BID AS eid,
    blog_title AS title,
    Time AS stime,
    blog_body AS description,
    UserName AS owner,
    r.replyID
  FROM blog_post b
  INNER JOIN replys r ON r.rid = b.BID
  WHERE b.action = "active" AND r.read = 1

  UNION

  SELECT
    "jaile" AS type,
    jid AS eid,
    orgname AS title,
    jaildate AS stime,
    OrgDescription AS description,
    jailorgnowner AS owner,
    null AS replyID
  FROM jailorgname

  UNION

  SELECT
    "articl" AS type,
    TID AS eid,
    Atitle AS title,
    Atime AS stime,
    Abody AS description,
    Auser AS owner,
    null AS replyID
  FROM articlespost
) foo
WHERE owner = :ownerna');
```

Comment: Sorry it worked, thank you very much

Comment: @Frank no problem. Next time you're having trouble with a SQL query, try running it in MySQL workbench, or from phpmyadmin, or whatever tool you have to run sql queries. That'll help you quickly identify errors.